# jQuery: How to copy container only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have HTML structure e.g.

```
<div id="mydiv" class="some" onclick="alert('Hello!')" style="background:red" >
   <div>aa</div>
   <div style="background:green" >bb</div> 
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pj5sn/

and I want

```
<div id="mydiv" class="some" onclick="alert('Hello!')" style="background:red" >
</div>
```

as a result. `.clone()` creates a deep copy but I need shallow copy.

**Edit**
All answers included till now do a deep copy and clear content. I intend to use it for several tens of containers each of them containing several tens of objects. I thing that it is necessary to have something more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I've used is a bit different.
First I create some structure and move the `div` content inside:

```
var $storage=$('<div/>').append($("#mydiv").children());
```

Now I can clone the remaining "shell" and move inside an appropriate part of the content:

```
$("#mydiv").clone(true,true).attr("id","d1")
     .appendTo($(document.body))
      .append($(":first-child",$storage));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KyTZ6/

Maybe it seems too complicated but my task was to divide an HTML table (~30 x 30) to six parts and I had performance problems with suggested cloning and clearing.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) first, and then use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) on the result.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks. But you were faster by whole 5 seconds :)

Comment: The example is simple but there can be lot of code inside and this does not seem very efficient.

Comment: @IvanH: Unless there is a real issue with performance I 'd suggest to take this and be glad it's so easy. Otherwise the only option is manually creating a new element of the same type and copying in all attributes from the source.

Comment: This is definitely the fastest, depending on the content level inside, It's best to dynamically create the element from the start and store it for later use.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be `$(this).clone().html('')`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to strip the content out of the div you're trying to clone.

```
var s = $('#mydiv').clone().html('');
$('#container').append(s);
```

​Simple, but works!

http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/Pj5sn/1/

There you go!